# OpenGL texturing using C++

Tags: c++, opengl, texturing

```
GLuint createTexture(const char* filename, int width = 128, int height = 128)
{
    GLuint texture;
    char bitmap[width][height][3];
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    assert(fp);
    assert(fread(bitmap, 3*sizeof(char), width*height, fp) == width*height);
    fclose(fp);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmap);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);

    return texture;
}
```

Hi people, I would like to know how the above code works. Supposedly it is a coding that can be used to texture solid objects in OpenGL (ex: `glutSolidSphere`). Can someone please explain to me how the above coding works?

Comment: As it's answered below: start by reading beginner tutorials. For more info on commands try looking openGL library reference like this one http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/

Answer (score 4):

You're sort of asking "How OpenGL works" and that depends on which version you're using. I would recommend: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials

Or better yet, read the "Red Book" (8th edition covers OpenGL 4.3)

http://www.opengl-redbook.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
GLuint createTexture(const char* filename, int width=128, int height=128)
{
    GLuint texture;
```

Use C99 variadic array to allocate width*height*3 bytes of memory on the stack. If there's not enough stack left, the program crashes with a stack overflow.

```
    char bitmap[width][height][3];
```

Try opening the file to fetch the texture from. The file must be a headerless, raw, tight array of 8 bit per channel RGB data.

```
    FILE* fp=fopen(filename, "rb");
```

Terminate the program if opening the file failed. Technically using assert for this purpose is a programming error, because a) assert does nothing in release builds and b) this is an easy to recover from error. The function should just return 0 if the file couldn't be opened.

```
    assert(fp);
```

Read width*height chunks of 3 bytes. `sizeof(char)` indicates the writer of this had no clue about C, because the C standard defines `sizeof(char) == 1`, so there's no point in doing that multiplication.

If not the expected amount of data could be read, crash the program if in debug mode. In case of error and a release build do strange things.

```
    assert(fread(bitmap, 3*sizeof(char), width*height, fp) == width*height);
```

Close the file.

```
    fclose(fp);
```

Allocate a OpenGL texture object handle.

```
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
```

Bind the texture handle so that subsequent OpenGL operations affecting textures are operating on the given object.

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
```

Set the texture magnification and minification filters. Use linear, so that mipmap levels are not required.

```
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Copy the data into the OpenGL texture. Since this uses a newly allocated texture object handle, the texture is also initialized by this.

A lot of important steps are missing here. Namely *glPixelStorei* must be used to prepare OpenGL to read data from the array. Line alignment, strides and so on.

```
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,bitmap);
```

Unbind the texture object.

```
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
```

Return texture object handle.

```
    return texture;
}
```

Major issues with this code: No OpenGL error checks and crashing the program if in debug builds. In release builds no file operation errors are detected and handled.

*DON'T USE THIS CODE!*